# Open large book on iBooks from my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, ibooks

I'm successfully opening a book on iBooks from my app with the following code. I'm using Xamarin but the code is the same so I don't think it's relevant.

```
NSString *stringURL = @"itms-books:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

My problem is opening large books. In this case around 800mb. After choosing "Open with.." and selected "iBooks" it takes a lot of time..almost a minute maybe until it "jumps" to iBooks app. Is this normal? Event after iBooks is opened it takes some time to load the file.

If this is normal..is there any way to get a progress of what's happening? So the user doesn't feel like nothing is happening.